# How to call multi table data in single page if all data is not related to each other

Tags: laravel

I have a controller named HomeController and I want to call data from banner table. I have a banner table and a BannerController. I had tried to get data in HomeController like

```
public function index()
{
    $data = banner::all();
    echo "hello";
    print_r($data);exit;
    return view('home');
}
```

but it's not showing me anything.
My banner model is like

```
<?php 
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class banner extends Model{
    protected $table='banners';
}
?>
```

And my route is like

```
Route::get('\home','HomeController@index')->name('home')
```

Comment: have you created a “banner” Eloquent model?

Comment: no, I am new to laravel can you show how I can do that

Comment: I have Banner Model in which i just define the table name like protected $table='banners'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model, assuming your table name is `'banners'`:

**App\Banner.php**

```
<?php 

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Banner extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'banners';
}
```

From HomeController, sending `$data` to your view can be done like so:

**App\Http\Controllers\HomeController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Banner;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $data = Banner::all();
        return view('home', compact('data'));
    }
}
```

And you should have the results of `Banner:all()` in your home blade/view which will be accessible as `$data`

---

In your blade file you can access it like so (just an example):

```
@foreach ($data as $banner)
    {{ $banner }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: It's saying class 'App\Http\Controllers\banner' not found and my controller name is BannerController

Comment: Not working having  class 'App\Http\Controllers\banner' not found error

Comment: I'm just basing my code on the information you are giving me. If i have more information on the model you are trying to use all() on i could give you proper advice.

Comment: I am just having protected $table='banners' in my model

Comment: make sure you import your model in your controller, i.e, add the line ```use App\banner;``` to the top of your HomeController class, below the ```namespace``` line, assuming that is the proper namespace / class name for your model

Comment: I had Added more details about my code please review

Comment: I have namespace App\Http\Controllers on the top of  the HomeController Do we need to call Banner as well

Comment: Which is fine, but below that you have to add what i mentioned in the previous comment in order to use the banner model.

Comment: It's saying illeagal offset type if i write use App\banner after the use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Answer (score 0):

**Try This Method - call multiple table data in a single page**

```
public function index()
{
    return View('index')
    ->with('test1', table1::all())
    ->with('test2', table2::all())
    ->with('test3', table3::all());
}
```

Comment: class 'App\Http\Controllers\banner' not found error is coming

Comment: Go to config/auth.php and change  App\Models\test::class.